# Take a screenshot of leaflet map

Tags: typescript, leaflet

So i have a leaflet map, on which i drew some layers(rectangles).
I want to capture a screenshot of that particular layer, not the whole visible map.
I've tried leaflet plugin, but they didn't work as i was expecting them to, and i've managed to capture the screenshot, but of the whole visible part of the map using html2canvas.
How could i select (capture) only that rectangle, which i want to be in the screenshot?

Or maybe its possible to capture selected area while using leaflet-area-select?

Im using react and typescript.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? **1**: Do you want a screenshot whose bounds are the bounds of the whole map, or do you want the screenshot's bounds to be the bounds of a given feature, essentially cropping the image to the feature? **2**. Do you want all layers present in the screenshot, or only a certain layer visible (no background tilelayer or controls, etc)? **3**: What kind of layers are you trying to capture here? Are these primarily L.Path layers, or are you also using markers / icons / image overlays?  GeoJSON?  **4** What is your desired output?

Comment: 1 - bounds of the given feature, cropping it
2 - only one layer, with a path on it, and the map itself too
3 - primarly l.path
4 - a png image, at least

Comment: What does "the map itself too" mean?  You mean with the baselayer?

Comment: Also, what version of react-leaflet are you using?

Comment: i'm using 1.7.1

Comment: You put in your tags that this is a react project...are you not using react-leaflet?

Comment: 1. im using plain leaflet, so i guess the answer to your question is no

2. and yes, i mean the baselayer


edit: this was not my decision to use plain leaflet, so it is what i have to use, because a lot of logic is already dependent on this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with the help of [leaflet-simple-map-screenshoter](https://github.com/grinat/leaflet-simple-map-screenshoter), and some careful image manipulation.

### [Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-bogdan-dqxse)

Here's a walkthrough of what I did:

#### Custom panes

First, lets create some [custom panes](https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/) to separate out what we want in the shot from what we dont.  Really all you're going to need is what layers you *dont* want in the screenshot, but we'll create two for good measure:

```js
//Create a map and assign it to the map div
var map = L.map("leafletMapid", mapOptions);

// Create some custom panes
map.createPane("snapshot-pane");
map.createPane("dont-include");
```

Now we can create our layers within those panes, whether they're tile layers or geojson or paths or whatever.  Lets include the baselayer and a geojson we want in the shot in the "snapshot-pane", and a path we dont want in the shot in the "dont-include" pane:

```js
// Add baselayer and geojson to snapshot pane
const baselayer = L.tileLayer(url,
  { pane: "snapshot-pane" }
).addTo(map);
const greekborder = L.geoJSON(greekBorderGeoJson, {
  pane: "snapshot-pane"
}).addTo(map);

// Add another polygon to the 'dont-include' pane
const serbianborder = L.polyline(serbianBorder, {
  color: "darkred",
  pane: "dont-include"
}).addTo(map);
```

#### Setting up a screenshotter:

Using the screenshot plugin, let's set up a screenshotter.  The screenshotter will **exclude** the layers we set in the "dont-include" pane:

```js
const snapshotOptions = {
  hideElementsWithSelectors: [
    ".leaflet-control-container",
    ".leaflet-dont-include-pane",
    "#snapshot-button"
  ],
  hidden: true
};

// Add screenshotter to map
const screenshotter = new SimpleMapScreenshoter(snapshotOptions);
screenshotter.addTo(map);
```

#### Custom screenshot function

We don't want to use the default screenshot behavior, so we'll assign a function to fire when we hit a custom button

```js
// define screenshot function
const takeScreenShot = () => {
  // defined below
}

// Add takescreenshot function to button
const button = document.getElementById("snapshot-button");
button.addEventListener("click", takeScreenShot);
```

If you check out the docs from the screenshot plugin, you can catch the image data created by the screenshotter in the `.then` that comes after the screenshot is taken:

```js
const takeScreenShot = () => {
  
screenshotter
    .takeScreen("image")
    .then((image) => {
      // Create <img> element to render img data
      var img = new Image();
    })

}
```

We've grabbed the image data, create a new `Image` element, and we're ready to assign the image data to the `new Image` element.  But before we do, we want to define an `img.onload` function that will fire at the moment the image data is assigned to the `Image` element.  This `onload` must be defined before we can assign the image source data.

#### What happens when the image loads

When the image loads, we want to do a few things

1. Find out the bounds of the relevant map feature
2. Translate those bounds to pixel coordinates on the screen
3. Write the image data contained **only** within those bounds to a canvas
4. Save that canvas as a png file

Here is the code to do that:

```js
img.onload = () => {
  // Create canvas to process image data
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // Set canvas size to the size of your resultant image
  canvas.width = imageSize.x;
  canvas.height = imageSize.y;

  // Draw just the portion of the whole map image that contains
  // your feature to the canvas
  ctx.drawImage(
    img,
    topLeft.x,
    topLeft.y,
    imageSize.x,
    imageSize.y,
    0,
    0,
    imageSize.x,
    imageSize.y
  );

  // Create URL for resultant png
  var imageurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

  const resultantImage = new Image();
  resultantImage.style = "border: 1px solid black";
  resultantImage.src = imageurl;

  // Append new image to body for nice visual in this example answer
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);

  canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
    // saveAs function installed as part of leaflet snapshot package
    saveAs(blob, "greek_border.png");
  });
};
```

Take your time to go through that and let me know if you have any questions.

An `Image.onload` function fires when the image `src` is assigned, so we define the function first, then assign the `src`:

```js
const takeScreenShot = () => {
  
screenshotter
    .takeScreen("image")
    .then((image) => {
      // Create <img> element to render img data
      var img = new Image();

      img.onload = () => {
        // all that code in the prev code block
      }

      // set the image source to what the snapshotter captured
      // img.onload will fire AFTER this
      img.src = image;
    })

}
```

And that's it.  You'll get an image downloaded that contains all layers of the map, except the controls, and whatever you excluded in the "dont-include" pane.  The image will be cropped to the bounds of your feature.

Note this will not work if part of the feature is outside of the visible map bounds.  While it is possible to achieve what you want with part of the feature outside of the map bounds, it is *far more complicated* to do that, especially if you want the baselayer in the background.

Also, you said initially you were using react.  I highly recommend using react-leaflet if you're using leaflet in a react project.  I initially wrote this answer as a react-leaflet answer, before you specified that you're not using it, but here is the react-leaflet version:

### [React-leaflet codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rl-snapshot-certain-layers-rl3-dvmpm)

Comment: I could use and adapt this code to my needs, but I get some unintended consequence, that when I save the image from the canvas, I get an image which has a small padding in the bottom-right borders. I also get this when I run your codesandbox, the saved images have some transparent parts, which shouldn't be. This padding is a huge problem, because it shifts the image from the original coordinates by a few pixels, which I don't really understand why or based on what logic it happens, so I can reverse engineer it. Have you run into this problem before? Do you know a quick fix?

Comment: It works nicely, I just have an observation, *map* on screenshotter.addTo(map) needs to be set on MapContainer component as a useState when using react-leaflet library, the setMapref is passed to the MapContainer prop ref (ref={setMapref}).

Answer (score 0):

**Use a Ref to Access the Map**: Utilize useState and useEffect to work with the map reference, ensuring that the map is fully loaded and your desired elements are rendered before taking the screenshot.

**Capture and Handle the Screenshot**: Implement the logic to capture the screenshot and handle the resulting image, such as logging or saving it.

I am using react-leaflet library so I came with something like this:

```
import L from "leaflet";
import { MapContainer } from "react-leaflet";
// Import SimpleMapScreenshoter after leaflet
import { SimpleMapScreenshoter } from 'leaflet-simple-map-screenshoter';
... // Inside your Map container component
const [mapRef, setMapRef] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  if (mapRef) {
    const snapshotOptions = {
      hideElementsWithSelectors: ["leaflet-control-simpleMapScreenshoter"], // by default hide map controls All els must be child of _map._container
      position: "topright",
      screenName: 'MapWithWellbore',
      hidden: false,
    };
    const simpleMapScreenshoter = new SimpleMapScreenshoter(snapshotOptions).addTo(mapRef);
    
    // Capture and handle screenshot
    simpleMapScreenshoter.takeScreen("image")
      .then(base64Image => {
        console.log(base64Image); // Process the image as needed
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.error(e.toString());
      });
  }
}, [mapRef]);

return (
  <MapContainer ref={setMapRef} attributionControl={false}>
    // Your map components here
  </MapContainer>
);

// Note: Ensure all map elements are rendered before taking the screenshot
```

Remember to handle cases where certain map elements might not be fully rendered when the screenshot is taken. Good luck with your endevour!

Take a thorough look at the library: https://github.com/grinat/leaflet-simple-map-screenshoter